# How do I find the ridges and valleys given a surface elevation function

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative, surfaces

Given a surface with a single elevation value for every x and y how can I find the places where the isoelevation contours have the tightest bends?  And how can I differentiate between bends that are ridges and bends that are valleys?  I've gone as far as finding the gradient in x and gradient in y and then found where these gradients change the most rapidly with respect to x and y and some combination of these 4 fields kind of gives me what I want, but I'm honestly at a loss here.  It's been a very long time since I've used basic multi-D calculus and could use a refresher!  Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the gradient of the surface and then find the [divergence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence) of the gradient vector field.